# The method putString(String, String) in the type SharedPreferences.Editor is not applicable for the arguments (String, InputStream)

Tags: java, android, attachment, email-attachments, fileoutputstream

I'm attempting to figure out a way to save the data from my InputStream and use it in another activity. So far I've tried to use sharedPreferences in the manner below - but I'm getting an error stating:

```
"The method putString(String, String) in the type SharedPreferences.Editor is not applicable for the arguments (String, InputStream)"
```

on the line:

```
editor.putString("fileName", attachment);
```

How might this be avoided?

### Source:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // get the attachment's filename
    Intent theIntent = getIntent();
    String attachmentFileName = "No file name found";
    if (theIntent != null && theIntent.getData() != null) {
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(theIntent.getData(), null,
                null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        final int fileNameColumnId = c
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        if (fileNameColumnId >= 0)
            attachmentFileName = c.getString(fileNameColumnId);

        try {

            InputStream attachment = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    getIntent().getData());
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("fileName", attachment);
            editor.commit();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store the `InputStream` in `SharedPreferences` because only primitive data (`int`,`boolean`,`String`, etc.) can be saved that way.

What you should do is read the data, save it to a `String` and then you can store the string [(see here)](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/10/06/how-to-read-data-from-inputstream-into-string-in-java/):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(attachment));
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    out.append(line);
}
```

then you can do

```
editor.putString("fileName", out.toString());
```

If you *really* want to send the actual `InputStream` to another activity (which is odd, but who am I to judge), however, you can do it using `intent.putSerializableExtra(attachment)`.

Comment: Thanks! I have another (simple) related issue you might be able to assist with / get credit for... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031936/android-java-unable-to-copy-files-from-sd-card

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences are an XML file that is designed to store small pieces of information. You're trying to save an attachment file to it. This is not really what shared prefereces are designed for. You should rather save the file on external or internal storage. See more [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).

As for your specific error, `putString()` method's second parameter is `String`. You would have to read your `InputStream` into a byte array and then transform it into a string (base 64? rememeber that attachments can be binary) which could be saved into shared preferences. But as I said above, I don't believe this is what you should be doing.

Comment: Thanks! I have another (simple) related issue you might be able to assist with / get credit for... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031936/android-java-unable-to-copy-files-from-sd-card

Answer (score 0):

Like the other said this is not possible with Sharedpreferences,  Keep it simple:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("fileName", attachmentFileName);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks! I have another (simple) related issue you might be able to assist with / get credit for... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031936/android-java-unable-to-copy-files-from-sd-card